# Merge [graphs] and [graph-theory] tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

These tags seem to be effectively interchangeable for all questions I've seen them used in. Should they be merged?

(Note: I agree [graph-neural-networks](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-neural-networks) should remain distinct.)

Comment: Maybe you could list the posts tagged with "graphs" that could be merged with "graph theory" (or maybe the ones where merging would not make sense).